# Как передать данные из DialogFragment в другой DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Пробовал использовать bundle, но почему-то возвращает `null`

В метод onCreate первого фрагмента `fmonday` (который должен принять данные) написал:

```
string1 =  getArguments().getString("latitude");
```

Из диалога `AlertDFragment` передаю данные:

```
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putString("latitude", string1);
       fmonday newfrag = new fmonday();
       newfrag.setArguments(bundle);
```

То есть, при срабатывании `onDismiss();` должно передать одну строковую переменную.

Что не так? Или есть другие выходы?

Comment: Вам уже кажется отвечали, что передавать надо через активити, а не напрямую из фрагмента в фрагмент. Или используйте какую-то шину, вроде *EventBus* или *Otto* для прямой передачи из фрагмента в фрагмент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `static` экземпляр класса с нужной инфой.

Например:

```
public class MyDataClass {
    public static MyDataClass sData;
    private int myData;
    private Context ctx; // необязательно, только если нужно использовать контекст в работе с данными
    ...

    public MyDataClass (Context ctx) {
         this.ctx = ctx;
         ...первичная инициализация myData;
    }

    public static MyDataClass get (Context ctx) {
        if (sData == null) sData = new MyDataClass (ctx);
        return sData;
    }

    public void setData (int data) {
        myData = data;
    }

    public int getData () {
        return myData;    
    } 

}
```

использование в `DialogFragment`:

```
 MyDataClass.get(getActivity()).setData();
 MyDataClass.get(getActivity()).getData();
```